# How to share credentials across multiple services accessing Google App

Tags: authentication, go, google-cloud-platform, microservices, credentials

First of all, I apologize in advance for my naïveté on the topic.

I am trying to create a few microservices that are exposed using an API gateway. A few of these services will need credentials from Google account to access Google Calendar/Gmail etc.. is there any way for a user to only have to login once so that the credentials are all shared between the services? Or should only one service be facing the Google services with credentials?

Comment: Is it possible for you to have a microservice behind a vpc that is internal facing. This service can communicate with a DB.  Your external services should be able to hit this internal service with some user identifier (user id) after they have logged in, to fetch google creds to be used on your public layer.  Your public facing services also have to be on the same vpc as your internal facing one to communicate with it, likely via some API -> GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE, to mod SQL or any db really. The google creds will have to be in the form of a refresh token so that you can use the oauth flow

Comment: Do you use kubernetes? If yes the you can store the token in a secret: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/secret

Answer (score 0):

It seems possible, you can ask a user to authenticate and authorize all permissions your application will need, all at once. But think about the user, when an application requires to access gmail, hangouts, photos, camera, etc. at once, the user normally disbelieve the application. So, the recommended approach is asking for the specific [permission when the application requires](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/CrossClientAuth) it so that the user can realize each action you app do.

There exist many different ways to address your question depending on details, however the following link can help you to know where to start:

- This link [(Google Sign-in)](https://developers.google.com/identity/choose-auth) has a wide context on all the Identity mechanisms to look for the most appropriate for you.
- This another one explain all possible [Identity mechanisms](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/) for specific use cases.

This [authentication example](https://developers.google.com/calendar/auth#OAuth2Authorizing) for Google Calendar is useful, but this post explain how [microservices authentication and authorization](https://medium.com/technology-learning/how-we-solved-authentication-and-authorization-in-our-microservice-architecture-994539d1b6e6) was solved.